# Oracle group by SQL query by matching varchar field

Tags: oracle, group-by

I have a table structure (that I did not design nor can I change) that uses a `varchar` field to store an attribute about the entity. I would like to write a SQL query to search for two attributes in particular and combine multiple result rows into single rows. To illustrate, my tables are similar to this:

```
company
=============
| id | name |
-------------
|  1 |  co1 |
|  2 |  co2 |
|  3 |  co3 |
=============

agent
====================================
| id | name | company_id |   type  |
------------------------------------
|  1 |  Tom |          1 | 'type1' |
|  2 |  Bob |          1 | 'type2' |
|  3 | Bill |          2 | 'type1' |
|  4 | Jack |          2 | 'type2' |
|  5 | John |          3 | 'type1' |
|  6 |  Joe |          3 | 'type2' |
====================================
```

`type1` and `type2` are hard-coded into the software as valid values (again, I didn't write it), so a search for these values should be successful (null is permitted). So, I must base my search off of these values.

As a novice, I could write this SQL:

```
select c.name, a.name, a.type
from company c
inner join agent a on c.id = a.company_id
```

and sort through these results in my software (Java program):

```
===========================
| c.name | a.name |  type |
---------------------------
|    co1 |   Tom |  type1 |
|    co1 |   Bob |  type2 |
|    co2 |  Bill |  type1 |
|    co2 |  Jack |  type2 |
|    co3 |  John |  type1 |
|    co3 |   Joe |  type2 |
===========================
```

But, I was hoping there would be a way to combine the rows into something more efficient:

```
-- my failed attempt at writing this query
select c.name, a.name as type_1_agent, a.name as type_2_agent
from company c
inner join agent a on c.id = a.company_id
group by c.id -- ?
where -- ?

results:

======================================
| name | type_1_agent | type_2_agent |
--------------------------------------
|  co1 |          Tom |          Bob |
|  co2 |         Bill |         Jack |
|  co3 |         John |          Joe |
======================================
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with PIVOT functionality, like so:

```
select company,type_1_agent,type_2_agent
from
(select a.name as agentname, a.type as agenttype,c.name as company
from agent a
inner join company c on c.id = a.company_id
) s
pivot
(max(agentname) for agenttype in ('type1' type_1_agent,'type2' type_2_agent)) p
order by company
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3cc08c/9)

Of course, in this case we hard coded the values for type. This can be made dynamic to accomodate an unknown number of these values.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle version:

```
WITH company (id, name) AS (
    SELECT 1, 'co1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'co2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'co3' FROM DUAL 
),
agent (id, name, company_id, type) AS (
    SELECT 1,  'Tom', 1, 'type1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,  'Bob', 1, 'type2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'Bill', 2, 'type1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'Jack', 2, 'type2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 'John', 3, 'type1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 6,  'Joe', 3, 'type2' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    company_name, type_1_agent, type_2_agent
FROM
    (SELECT company.name company_name, agent.name agent_name, type FROM company JOIN agent ON company.id = agent.company_id)
    PIVOT (
        MAX(agent_name) agent
        FOR type IN ('type1' type_1, 'type2' type_2)
    )
ORDER BY
    company_name
```